# Django Foreign Key error ......What should I do now?

Tags: python, django, database, foreign-keys, save

````
```In [1]: import json

In [2]: from Bugijugi. models import Post

In [3]: with open('posts.json') as f:
   ...:     posts_json = json.load(f)
   ...: 

In [4]: for post in posts_json:
   ...:     post = Post(title=post['title'], content=post['content'], author_id=post['us 
   ...: er_id'])
   ...:     post.save()
   ...: ```
````

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IntegrityError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py:97,
> in DatabaseErrorWrapper.**call**..inner(*args, **kwargs)
> 96 with self:
> ---> 97     return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> IntegrityError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [4], in <cell line: 1>()
> 1 for post in posts_json:
> 2     post = Post(title=post['title'], content=post['content'], author_id=post['user_id'])
> ----> 3     post.save()
>
> File F:\IMPORTANT\GAME\vrsty life\CSE
> 347\Project\Sample\Bugijugi\models.py:27, in Post.save(self)
> 26 def save(self):
> ---> 27     return super().save()
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py:743,
> in Model.save(self, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
> 740     if loaded_fields:
> 741         update_fields = frozenset(loaded_fields)
> --> 743 self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
> 744                force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py:780,
> in Model.save_base(self, raw, force_insert, force_update, using,
> update_fields)
> 778     if not raw:
> 779         parent_inserted = self._save_parents(cls, using, update_fields)
> --> 780     updated = self._save_table(
> 781         raw, cls, force_insert or parent_inserted,
> 782         force_update, using, update_fields,
> 783     )
> 784 # Store the database on which the object was saved
> 785 self._state.db = using
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py:885,
> in Model._save_table(self, raw, cls, force_insert, force_update,
> using, update_fields)
> 882     fields = [f for f in fields if f is not meta.auto_field]
> 884 returning_fields = meta.db_returning_fields
> --> 885 results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
> 886 if results:
> 887     for value, field in zip(results[0], returning_fields):
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py:923,
> in Model._do_insert(self, manager, using, fields, returning_fields,
> raw)
> 918 def _do_insert(self, manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw):
> 919     """
> 920     Do an INSERT. If returning_fields is defined then this method should
> 921     return the newly created data for the model.
> 922     """
> --> 923     return manager._insert(
> 924         [self], fields=fields, returning_fields=returning_fields,
> 925         using=using, raw=raw,
> 926     )
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py:85,
> in
> BaseManager._get_queryset_methods..create_method..manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 84 def manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
> ---> 85     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py:1301,
> in QuerySet._insert(self, objs, fields, returning_fields, raw, using,
> ignore_conflicts)    1299 query = sql.InsertQuery(self.model,
> ignore_conflicts=ignore_conflicts)    1300 query.insert_values(fields,
> objs, raw=raw)
> -> 1301 return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py:1448,
> in SQLInsertCompiler.execute_sql(self, returning_fields)    1446 elif
> self.connection.features.can_return_columns_from_insert:    1447
> assert len(self.query.objs) == 1
> -> 1448     rows = [self.connection.ops.fetch_returned_insert_columns(    1449         cursor, self.returning_params,    1450     )]    1451
> else:    1452     rows = [(self.connection.ops.last_insert_id(    1453
> cursor, opts.db_table, opts.pk.column,    1454     ),)]
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\operations.py:185,
> in BaseDatabaseOperations.fetch_returned_insert_columns(self, cursor,
> returning_params)
> 180 def fetch_returned_insert_columns(self, cursor, returning_params):
> 181     """
> 182     Given a cursor object that has just performed an INSERT...RETURNING
> 183     statement into a table, return the newly created data.
> 184     """
> --> 185     return cursor.fetchone()
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py:96,
> in DatabaseErrorWrapper.**call**..inner(*args, **kwargs)
> 95 def inner(*args, **kwargs):
> ---> 96     with self:
> 97         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py:90,
> in DatabaseErrorWrapper.**exit**(self, exc_type, exc_value, tracebackn
> DatabaseErrorWrapper.**exit**(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
> 88 if dj_exc_type not in (DataError, IntegrityError):
> 89     self.wrapper.errors_occurred = True
> ---> 90 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py:97,
> in DatabaseErrorWrapper.**call**..inner(*args, **kwargs)     n
> DatabaseErrorWrapper.**call**..inner(*args, **kwargs)
> 95 def inner(*args, **kwargs):
> 96     with self:
> ---> 97         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

`author_id` value is not a valid id of `Author` in the database. You need to create authors with ids matching values in the `author_id` field first before setting them in the `Post` model.